# Titanium Backup - Restoring manually backed up apps (TB, Google Drive)

Tags: applications, backup, data-recovery, titanium-backup, 7.1-nougat

I recently had to format my OnePlus 2 and backed up a few apps, namely Authenticator and two games. First, I did a normal backup, then I used "send latest backup" in the "special features" tab to put the backup into my Google Drive (I didn't know about the sync feature then). Now, TB won't restore the apps after I 1) manually copied the .TIBKP files from my Google Drive to the detected (!) folder on my OP2's internal storage and 2) linked my Drive and used the Sync button in the schedules list to download all backups. The backups don't show up in "Backup/Restore", it says "no backup yet".

I've tried clearing the App's cache which didn't help unfortunately.

I went through all steps on the [technical FAQ site](https://www.titaniumtrack.com/kb/titanium-backup-kb/titanium-backup-technical-faq.html#how-restore-backups-dropbox-if-sd-card-fail-or-stolen) numerous times without success.

I am running Linage OS 14.1 (August 31), rooted using their suaddon. F2FS on data and cache.

These backups are very important to me, I have about a dozen accounts linked with my Authenticator which would all be lost. I greatly appreciate all attempts at helping me.

Comment: Have you tried "starting" the `.tibkp` file with a file manager? That should have TiBu open it, as it's registered for that file extension.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither the built-in "Files" manager nor  Root Browser let me open the file with TB, can you recommend another file browser with that feature?

Comment: Nevermind, it worked with Root Browser, I just couldn't find the app in the list at first. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: As you confirmed it worked out, I've made it an answer. Please "tick" the check-mark next to it to indicate this as your "working solution" (see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) for the idea behind that concept).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Titanium Backup* would ask you to restore the `.tibkp` file if you "share" it to it directly. Easiest way to do so is using a file manager and "tap" the `*.tibkp` – as *Titanium Backup* is associated with that file extension, you should be offered to share it that way.

As you confirmed, *Root Browser* is a file manager capable of that. Most others should do as well, though some might be "too restricted" in their functionality as you found out, e.g. the built-in file manager.